# SVN (Subversion) not working properly in Android Studio 3.1.3

Tags: android, svn, svn-checkout

I can import projects to Subversion and check them out. However, after a checkout, I get errors with many library functions not being recognised (red squiggly lines) and the app does not work. Also, sometimes the design view experiences rendering problems and none of the objects appear (just a blank screen in design and blue print view). This problem arose since updating to v3.1.3. Previously, I had no issues SVN worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

OK, problem solved. As I suspected, it was the update that did it. API 28 causes these problems. Downgrading to API 27 solved both issues.

**Tools->SDK Manager->System Setting->Android SDK** then un-tick Android API 28 but make sure that you have API 27 (or any other API that you require ticked)